# Insert 2 values from two different tables into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I have a problem with insert 2 values from 2 different tables during inserting to third table.

First table is:

- author_id (PK)
- author_name
- author_email

Second table is:

- category_id (PK)
- category_name

Third table is:

- post_id
- post_category
- post_author
- post_title
- post_content
- post_date

and I want get  `author_name` from the first table and `category_name` from the second table during inserting data into third table.

I got something like this but it's not working.

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_category, post_author, post_title, post_content) 
    SELECT 
        category_name 
    FROM 
        categories 
    WHERE 
        category_name='python', 
    SELECT 
        author_name 
    FROM
        authors 
    WHERE
       author_name = 'm0jito', 
    'Lorem Ipsum', 
    'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum ')
```

Looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides @sagi's solution you should be able to use Scalar Subqueries in an `INSERT VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_category, post_author, post_title, post_content) 
VALUES
  (
    (SELECT 
        category_name 
    FROM 
        categories 
    WHERE 
        category_name='python'), 
    (SELECT 
        author_name 
    FROM
        authors 
    WHERE
       author_name = 'm0jito'), 
    'Lorem Ipsum', 
    'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum '
  )
```

This will fail if `category_name`or `author_name` are not unique.

Btw, you probably want to return the category/author *id* instead of the *name*, because the current SELECT is not needed at all. But I assume this was just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join these tables together :

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_category, post_author, post_title, post_content) 
SELECT c.category_name,a.author_name,'Lorem Ipsum','Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum'
FROM categories c
CROSS JOIN authors a
WHERE c.category_name = 'python'
  AND a.author_name = 'm0jito'
```

I used `CROSS JOIN` because you didn't provide any relations between those two tables(a little suspicious) , if there is some sort of relation column, change it to an `INNER JOIN` and use the `ON()` clause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)